# I need a 12v two way non locking toggle switch both sides must have a NC and a NO when switched on NC must open NO must close I'm not an electrician

Tags: switches, 12v

1. 2 way non locking toggle switch
2. both sides NO & NC
3. When switched NO must close NC must open

Comment: What is your answerable EE question? Purchase advice is explicitly [off topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Home wiring is on topic at [Home Improvement.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: (You may be looking for [DPDT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology).)

Comment: "Locking" has a specific meaning, you wouldn't specify "non-locking". You probably want a 3 position switch, with both sides "momentary". However, I have never seen a switch with NO and NC contacts for both momentary positions. Common choices are Mom-On-Mom, or Mom-Off-Mom. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/toggle-switches/201

Comment: Would be good if you specified voltages and currents to be switched.  There is a big difference between a switch for logic levels or a switch for high voltages.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you plan something. Let's call it Y. And you have reasoned that Y needs the still unknown momentary 2 side toggle switch X where the sides have opposite idle states.

Walking through a pile of catalogs of switch manufacturers may lead you to the wanted switch X. That's not sure and it's well possible that nobody is interested in selling to you one. But it's a possibility, anyway. I'm afraid you must do the searching by yourself.

Another possibility is to mechanically disassemble and customize an existing switch. Customitzing a miniature size device is a hard job, beyond the possibilities of most of us. But I have disassembled a couple of 230VAC room light switches to get one new functionality switch. The result worked well in a circuit which had 15 volts DC. Big size was actually just a plus in my application. Fortunately I needed only one and the application didn't need a certified part. Customizing house mains AC switches is fully illegal where I live.

Alternatively you can build a mechanical locking frame which forces 2 different switches to turn together. Challenges: Sturdy enough construction, how to make easily more than one, if needed.

The 3rd possibility is to redesign. You may use a simple one circuit switch if you have a relay or other circuitry which does the more complex switching. A relay is trivial, but there can be something more effective. To show it we may help, but that's possible only if we know enough details of the actual Y.

Comment: Tagged 12v and repeated in the title, I don't expect dangerous voltages are to be handled. Then again, switching high currents has its own challenges.